# Getting MySQL to use multiple indices per table

Tags: mysql, indexing

I remember reading somewhere that MySQL can use only 1 index per table for a `SELECT` query, I don't know if this is still true for recent versions of MySQL. I couldn't find anything about the topic.

I'm trying to optimize a query on a table that has multiple indices, but `EXPLAIN` shows that it's using only 1 of the indices. I tried using `FORCE INDEX(index1,index2)`, but that isn't working. Is there a way to force MySQL to use multiple indices in a table?

I'm using MySQL 5.6.15.

Comment: Can you show the query and table definition?

Comment: reading two indexes means doing two queries and then merging result sets is going to be slower than using one index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically MySql can use only one index while retrieving rows from the table.

However there are special cases when MySql is able to scan multiple indexes from a single table.

This is called **index merge optimalization** and details are describes under this link:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-merge-optimization.html

A few basic examples you can find in this [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a11dc/4)

There is a couple of indexes on `mytable` table in this demo:

```
create index m_x on mytable( x );
create index m_y on mytable( y );
```

And there are three queries (you need to click on `view execution plan` links in this demo to see their expains):

Intersection access algorithm:

```
select *
from mytable
where x = 4 
  and y = 7
;
POSSIBLE_KEYS = m_x,m_y
KEY           = m_x,m_y
EXTRA         = Using intersect(m_x,m_y); Using where
```

Union access algorithm:

```
select *
from mytable
where x = 5 
   or y = 3
;
POSSIBLE_KEYS = m_x,m_y
KEY           = m_x,m_y
EXTRA         = Using union(m_x,m_y); Using where
```

Sort union access algorithm:

```
select *
from mytable
where  x > 49 or y < 1 
;
POSSIBLE_KEYS = m_x,m_y
KEY           = m_x,m_y
EXTRA         = Using sort_union(m_x,m_y); Using where
```

If there are a few indexes created on the table, then MySql always tries to apply these optimizations automatically, you don't need to do anything special to turn on them except creating indexes.
However MySql uses these optimalizations only in very special and rare cases. 
In other cases a combined index (single index on multiple columns) can be used